# NodeJS 14 crash on nestJS project run on macOS Catalina

Tags: node.js, macos, nestjs

I was having troubles running a project on an iMac that was given to me. Node was continuing to crash with a nasty error, which I had no clue of what it was.
So I thought that the previous computer owner had something messed up. I decided to re install macOS from scratch, and have a clean environment to start with.

The surprising problem is that on a **brand new**  mac installation without any other software or configurations changes node keeps blowing up with this error:

```
 1: 0x1012e2bc5 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000a5cb9 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x100114d99 node::Abort(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x100259878 v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x100258e0c v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x100258532 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x100a796d9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x100a129a2 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
```

#### Strange thing:

I'd expect this to blow on every single machine if there was a "coding" problem, but the problem is that the same code, on a docker container, or on my currently in use macbook pro (running Mojave) runs without any problem.

I've also tried to downgrade to node 12, but with no effect. The same problem keeps hunting me, and I'm a bit desperate since I was working on this project since a month now, and I have no clue of what could generate this error.

I thought that it was an environment configuration error, so before bothering you with any useless issue, I have formatted the iMac and installed a brand new copy of mac, without any further "touches" except for the installation of node 14. I was in panic when I saw the same error repeat on a clean environment.

I expect the same code to run on every machine or to break on every machine.
I am totally clueless. I don't even know what this error means, and Google wasn't helpful to me.

Even a clarification of what this error is would help, perhaps investigating on the root cause...

### Environment

- Nest version: 7.5.1
- Node version: 14.15.1
- Platform: macOS Catalina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No words for this... It was a freaking folder missing while trying to write files on it. Why didn't node 14 complain about it? Shouldn't it throw an error like ENONET??